# Python: Astar algorithm implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, game, pathfinding, a-star

I have implemented Astar algorithm for a problem on an online judge relating to maze given start and end positions along with a grid representing the maze. I output the length of the path along with the path itself. The following is the implementation in Python using the Euclidean distance:

```
import heapq, math, sys

infinity = float('inf')

class AStar():

    def __init__(self, start, grid, height, width):
        self.start, self.grid, self.height, self.width = start, grid, height, width

    class Node():
        def __init__(self, position, fscore=infinity, gscore=infinity, parent = None):
            self.fscore, self.gscore, self.position, self.parent = fscore, gscore, position, parent
            
        def __lt__(self, comparator):
            return self.fscore < comparator.fscore

    def heuristic(self, end, distance = "Euclidean"):
        (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = self.start, end
        if (distance == "Manhattan"):
            return abs(x1 - x2) + abs(y1 - y2)
        return math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)

    def nodeNeighbours(self, pos):
        (x, y) = pos
        return [(dx, dy) for (dx, dy) in [(x + 1, y), (x - 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x, y - 1)] if 0 <= dx < self.width and 0 <= dy < self.height and self.grid[dy][dx] == 0]

    def getPath(self, endPoint):
        current, path = endPoint, []
        while current.position != self.start:
            path.append(current.position)
            current = current.parent
        path.append(self.start)
        return list(reversed(path))

    def computePath(self, end):
        openList, closedList, nodeDict = [], [], {}
        currentNode = AStar.Node(self.start, fscore=self.heuristic(end), gscore = 0)
        heapq.heappush(openList, currentNode)
        while openList:
            currentNode = heapq.heappop(openList)
            if currentNode.position == end:
                return self.getPath(currentNode)
            else:
                closedList.append(currentNode)
                neighbours = []
                for toCheck in self.nodeNeighbours(currentNode.position):
                    if toCheck not in nodeDict.keys():
                        nodeDict[toCheck] = AStar.Node(toCheck)
                        neighbours.append(nodeDict[toCheck])
                
                for neighbour in neighbours:
                    newGscore = currentNode.gscore + 1
                    if neighbour in openList and newGscore < neighbour.gscore:
                        openList.remove(neighbour)
                    if newGscore < neighbour.gscore and neighbour in closedList:
                        closedList.remove(neighbour)
                    if neighbour not in openList and neighbour not in closedList:
                        neighbour.gscore = newGscore
                        neighbour.fscore = neighbour.gscore + self.heuristic(neighbour.position)
                        neighbour.parent = currentNode
                        heapq.heappush(openList, neighbour)
                    heapq.heapify(openList)
        return None
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    sys.stdin = open('input.txt', 'r')
    sys.stdout = open('output.txt', 'w')
    
    matrix = [[int(num) for num in line.split()] for line in sys.stdin]
    size = matrix.pop(0)
    coordinates = matrix.pop(0)
    n, m = size[0], size[1]
    x1, y1, y2, x2 = coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[2], coordinates[3]
    path = AStar((x1-1, y1-1), matrix, n, m).computePath((y2-1, x2-1))
    print(len(path))
    for pos in path:
        print(pos[0] + 1, pos[1] + 1)
```

Comment: I do not have anything else to say yet, but your Manhattan distance code seems to be wrong (it currently is `abs((x1 - x2) + abs(y1 - y2))` but should probably be `abs(x1 - x2) + abs(y1 - y2)`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
self.start, self.grid, self.height, self.width = start, grid, height, width
```

I would not put these all on the same line like that. I think it would be much easier to read spread over multiple lines:

```
self.start = start
self.grid = grid
self.height = height
self.width = width
```

---

I would probably have the `Node` class as toplevel instead of nested. I don't think you're gaining much by having it inside `AStar`. You could name it `_Node` to make it "module-private" so that attempting to import it to another file will potentially raise warnings.

In `Node`'s `__lt__` implementation, I wouldn't call the second parameter `comparator`. A comparator is something that compares, whereas in this case, that's just another node. `other_node` or something would be more appropriate.

---

In `heuristic`, I'd personally make use of an `else` there:

```
if (distance == "Manhattan"):
    return abs((x1 - x2) + abs(y1 - y2))
else:
    return math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
```

It makes it clearer that only one of the lines will be executed. Personally, I only neglect the `else` in a case like that if the `if` was an "early exit" precondition check, and I want to avoid nesting the entire rest of the function inside a block. That's not a problem here though.

---

`nodeNeighbors` ([which should be `node_neighbors`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)) would be cleaner broken over several lines:

```
def nodeNeighbours(self, pos):
    (x, y) = pos
    return [(dx, dy)
            for (dx, dy) in [(x + 1, y), (x - 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x, y - 1)]
            if 0 <= dx < self.width and 0 <= dy < self.height and self.grid[dy][dx] == 0]
```

I think that makes it a lot easier to see what's going on in it.

---

Again, in many places you're assigning two or more variables on one line:

```
(x1, y1), (x2, y2) = self.start, end
current, path = endPoint, []
openList, closedList, nodeDict = [], [], {}
x1, y1, y2, x2 = coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[2], coordinates[3]
```

I would break those up. Especially once you get to 3+ on a line, for the reader to see what variable matches up with what value, they'll need to count from the left instead of just checking what's on each side of a `=`.

---

In `computePath`, it seems like  `closedList` should be a set. It doesn't appear as though order matters with it, and `neighbour in closedList` will be faster with a set than it will with a list. It looks though like `openList` is required to be a list though due to it being passed to `heapify`.

---

I don't think I'd reassign `stdin` and `stdout`. The reassignment of `stdin` seems completely unnecessary, and changing `stdout` will make it harder to debug later using `print` statements. You don't necessarily want *all* printed text to be sent to the file.

If need-be, you can specify what file you want printed to when printing:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as out_f:
    print("To file!", file=out_f)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you think using openList a  `priority_queue` instead will make the code more efficient than using heapq?

Comment: @JalanjiMoh Honestly, it's been a long time since I've written a A* implementation, so it's difficult for me to make algorithmic suggestions here. Even if you did switch though, you likely still wouldn't be able to have `open_list` as a set for the same reason. Standard Python sets are unordered, so any place you need to maintain order, plain sets won't be appropriate.